# Different margins in constraintlayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I created a launchpad using constraintlayout for Android. I added buttons for the launchpad and used the chain functionality for arrange some buttons in rows and columns.

As you can see in picture, the space between the rows (marked with red color) are larger than the space between the columns (marked with blue color) are now equal, which is a problem i could not solve alone. 
How can I get the same space?

[image: Buttons in constrainslayout]

Here are my button definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/taalsLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/geda"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/geda"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mogholi"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/kehrwa"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/kehrwa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/kehrwa"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rupak"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dadra"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/geda"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/geda" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/dadra"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/dadra"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tapea"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/kehrwa"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/kehrwa" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/mogholi"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/mogholi"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sitarkhani"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rupak"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/geda" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/rupak"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/rupak"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/japtaal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tapea"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mogholi"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mogholi" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/tapea"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/tapea"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/teentaal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rupak"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rupak" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/sitarkhani"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/sitarkhani"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ektaal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/japtaal"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mogholi" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/japtaal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/japtaal"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/C"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/teentaal"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sitarkhani"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sitarkhani" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/teentaal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/teentaal"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/D"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/japtaal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/japtaal" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/ektaal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/ektaal"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/C"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sitarkhani" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/C"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="سا"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/D"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ektaal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ektaal" />

<com.mapani.launchpad.XButton
    android:id="@+id/D"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/C" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Because Row And Column Size Differs in Height and Width Of the Layout.Reducing The Button Width Will Allow U to Equalise Column Height.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is this the only way? Is it not possible to change this in layout. Because, I am not sure which with do I have to set for the Button

Comment: I have tried this  setWidth(getHeight()); in costructor of my Button which subclassed android Button. Nothing has changed

Comment: Otherwise Take the Space Between the Row and put the Spacing as Constraints for the Buttons in Column wise,So that you Will Be Getting Equal Row and Column Spacing

Comment: Thank you again. Would you help me with some code. I do not know how to do this.